# Check if android adapter supports 5GHz frequency WIFI

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I would like to know how to use WifiManager to check if my device wifi adapter supports 5Ghz frequency or not. Small snippet for android code would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [is5GHzBandSupported()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#is5GHzBandSupported()) from Android API Level 21.

This way:

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.is5GHzBandSupported()
```

Comment: This worked for me. May be the only thing to add is that this permission is requiered (is not a dangerous permission)  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />